# DESCEND's function 'selectGenes' takes forever to finish on sparse matrix, and also shows no error message

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, sparse-matrix, rna-seq

I have a sparse matrix of dimension 33694*10000, which I had converted into data frame and then coerced into a matrix. I am using DESCEND  and SOUP (semisoft clustering of single-cell data) to filter out highly variable genes from the matrix and in turn, perform clustering.

The function "selectGenes" from SOUP is taking too long to finish however earlier it took two days to finish the same task (different matrix but same dimensions). I have checked my matrix for any missing values or NAs but the matrix seems fine. Or maybe I need to look for some other kind of error in my matrix because the test data is running fine and taking the usual time to finish the run.

I don't know how to troubleshoot this because I cannot see any error my screen just looks like this.

```
select.out_SP1_mat = selectGenes(SP1_mat_transposed, type="count", n.cores=25)

> select.out_SP1_mat = selectGenes(SP1_mat_transposed, type="count", n.cores=25)
Removed 32820 genes that are expressed in less than 10 cells.
Selecting from remaining 874 genes...
SPCA selection...
DESCEND selection...
[1] "DESCEND starts deconvolving distribution of 874 genes!"
[1] "Estimating the time to finish this task ..."
```

Here is the link to SOUP tutorial pdf and the code for function "selectGenes":

https://github.com/lingxuez/SOUPR/blob/master/vignettes/SOUP-vignette.pdf

https://rdrr.io/github/lingxuez/SOUP/src/R/geneSelect.R

https://rdrr.io/github/jingshuw/descend/src/R/descend.R

Can anyone suggest how do I troubleshoot or solve this issue? I am running this on cluster having 64 cores and 1 Tb RAM.

This is what I did before running the function mentioned:

```
library(SOUP)
library(ggplot2)
> SP1 <-read.table(file = "/home/mverma/SINGLE_CELL_data/spleen/raw_gene_bc_matrices/spleen_subset_test/analysis/SP1_matrix.tsv", sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
> SP1_mat <- as.matrix(x = SP1)
> dim(SP1_mat)
[1] 33694 10000
> SP1_mat_transposed <- t(SP1_mat)
> dim(SP1_mat_transposed)
[1] 10000 33694

> log.expr_SP1_mat= log2(scaleRowSums(SP1_mat_transposed)*(10^6) + 1)
> dim(log.expr_SP1_mat)
[1] 10000 33694

> select.out_SP1_mat = selectGenes(SP1_mat_transposed, type="count", n.cores=25)
Removed 32820 genes that are expressed in less than 10 cells.
Selecting from remaining 874 genes...
SPCA selection...
DESCEND selection...
[1] "DESCEND starts deconvolving distribution of 874 genes!"
[1] "Estimating the time to finish this task ..."
```

Comment: Why don't you just throw out the 32820 features that are getting filtered and then just give this function a 10k x 800 dense matrix? That's tiny, I could fit that on my phone's memory.

Comment: mm I'm not familiar with the packages but maybe this can help a little: You mentioned coercing between dataframe and matrix. Performing calculations on matrix can be much faster than datarames so try keep calculations on matrices. Improvements in serieal are the best starting point but if you have 64 cores can you do computations in parallel (check out the package `parallel`)? Finally if there are any time/memory issues loading and saving bit data check out the `fst` (i use this one) package or `bibmemoy`.

Comment: @CJR Thank you for your suggestion but I am not sure it's gonna work because the function is already filtering the data out first and then continuing further with shorter data. However, I have filtered out the genes as per suggestion, will mention it if that works. Thank you!

Comment: @QAsena Thanks a lot! yes, I did coerce the data frame into matrix and then performed the calculations. Actually, the function has two parts SPCA selection which is fast, and DESCEND which is computationally exhaustive thus has already been parallelized in the code (using doParallel), but the problem is that my data passes the SPCA part but gets stuck after that and doesn't reach the parallelization part. Which is confusing for me because I cannot find out why. Saving and loading of data is not a problem in my case atleast.

Comment: The people who wrote this package couldn't be bothered to write a testing framework for it. It's probably just broken. (it's probably also broken garbage when it does manage to run end-to-end, so it's really doing you a favor by failing now instead of just giving you useless, broken results).